# Store imap.fetch result in a variable and iterate anytime

Tags: node.js, node-imap

I am trying to store the result from imap.fetch() into a variable, so that i can iterate it whenever i want to check all mail.
But it is not working when i call my getAllMail() from another class, Thanks for any help.

```
let allSearch;

imap.search(['All', ['ON', date]], (err,res) => {
   if (err) console.log(err)
   else {
     allSearch = imap.fetch(res, {bodies:'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM SUBJECT)', struct:true})
   }       
})

function getAllMail() {
  allSerch.on('message', (msg, seq) => {
    console.log()   
  })
}

module.exports.getAllMail = getAllMail
```